# how do you make a collection show up in reverse order using expressJS partials/collections?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using an **index.jade** to show:

```
!=partial('_blogPost.jade', blogPost)
```

and in **_blogPost.jade**:

```
div.row-fluid
    div.span2.sider
        h4.date 
            #{blogPost.addedOn.getDate()}/#{blogPost.addedOn.getMonth() + 1}
            |#{blogPost.addedOn.getFullYear()}
        h3
            #{blogPost.type}
    div.span9.post
        h2 
            a(href="#{blogPost.url}") !{blogPost.title}
        p !{blogPost.body}
```

Pretty standard blogrolling stuff.
Using a standard for loop what I'm looking for would be:

```
for(var i = blogPost.length-1; i >= 0; i --){
 blogPost[i].body
etc...
}
```

The problem is, **how do you make a collection show up in reverse order using expressJS partials/collections?**

Comment: couldn't you just say `blogPost.reverse()` before using it in the template file?!

Comment: i actually had no idea the reverse() function existed. I googled around for a good half an hour but was looking for a jade/express way to solve it. Can you write that as an answer so i can mark it as correct? It worked just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just say

```
blogPost.reverse();
```

before using it inside your jade template and the content of the array will be shown in reverse order.

Comment: True -- note, though, that `Array.prototype.reverse` will reverse the array in place, and so mutates the array. If that is not what you want, you can create a copy and reverse that with `blogPost.slice(0).reverse()`.